# Shopping cart rules: Autogenerated unique codes, applicable to any product with different discounts

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, coupon, promotions, coupon-codes

I need to generate a number of unique coupon codes. Any of those coupon codes could be used for any of the products. The problem is that different products need to get different discounts.

Seems to me I can't create different rules for every product because the rules wouldn't share the same set of coupons.

Is such a thing even possible?

Magento Version 1.9.2.2

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a way to do that natively in Magento.

I would look maybe in the extension created by Amasty
https://amasty.com/special-promotions.html
and 
https://amasty.com/special-promotions-pro.html

Otherwise you will have to do as you said: different shopping Cart Price Rule, restricted for each set of product. But then as you mentionned you will not share the set of Coupon Codes generated.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've contacted them, unfortunately they said that their module wouldn't help here.